# Split by multiple characters

Tags: c#, split

The result of doing

```
var b = "asfsadefbweabgggggggggggg".Split("ab".ToCharArray());
```

is a list of 6 strings while I want to split the array in `"asfsadefbwe"` and `"gggggggggggg"`. Is there any way/method to properly do that (with C#)?

PS: I'll use a string which has some data separate by `"\r\n"` secuences.

Comment: maybe write a method that finds the last occurance of sample string (in your case "ab") and split on there?

Comment: Maybe is duplicated but I couldn't finde the right wording to find it, sorry.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
string[] list = b.Split(new string[] { "ab" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 12):

Use another overload, one that doesn't split on individual characters:

```
 "asfsadefbweabgggggggggggg".Split(new [] {"ab" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your substrings always the same length? If so, use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).